# Взаимодействие Windows-программ на уровне форм

Tags: windows

Есть программа (exe-шник, не моя) с формой. Одно единственное поле: логин.
Моё желание - организовать автозаполнение - вставить строку в данное поле программы.

Вопрос: в какой области искать решение задачи (системные скрипты, ЯП высокого уровня, обратная разработка или что-то иное).
Совсем идеально - получить принцип реализации.

Comment: Поиск окна + отправка ему сообщения WM_SETTEXT как вариант.

Comment: Отсюда (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100605/settext-of-textbox-in-external-app-win32-api)